# Allow a view to display below the android popup keyboard

Tags: android

I want to implement a view that will always display below the keyboard like the image below, how can I achieve this?

I used a BottomNavigationView in a constraintLayout.

[image]

layout_marginBottom didnt work for me , also tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" which didnt give the result

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The System behavior is for the keyboard to be at the bottom.  That can actually be overridden, but it's the keyboard app that needs to override that behavior, not the user.  And even then your app wouldn't be able to control where the keyboard displays, the keyboard app would be in control of that as well (and would have no idea what views your app has onscreen).  The main use of the keyboard app override is to make smaller keyboards or dragable ones on tablets.  There's nothing in that API that would allow an app to request a keyboard display in a certain place.

Comment: in some newer dumbphones  based on Android they have an option bar showing below the ime keyboard, I wonder how.

Comment: @Harry If its a feature of the phone then they could customize the OS to do that.  If you're programming your own device you could get that to work.  But its not part of an app.